# How to embed youtube video into a facebook iframe app?

Tags: facebook, video, iframe, youtube, embed

I wanted to make a facebook app with an image which has 2 buttons and under the image there would be a video from youtube. But since coding is new to me I need your help. I tried different codes but none of them worked. the video is not appearing at all. 
And heres the final code I came up with:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com /2008/fbml">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function framesetsize(w,h){
var obj =   new Object;
obj.width=w;
obj.height=h;
FB.Canvas.setSize(obj);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="framesetsize(520,3300)"> <!--specify the height and width for resize-->
<div id="fb-root">

<div align="center"><img src="http://fb.joma-sport.hu/jomafiuk4.jpg" width="520" height="390" border="0" usemap="#Map" /></p>
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area shape="rect" coords="133,74,246,335" href="2.htm" target="_self" alt="Total fit" />
<area shape="rect" coords="248,43,414,339" href="3.htm" target="_self" alt="Aluminio" />
</map></div>
</div> 
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="650" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUaxZLJ0-28" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div
</div>
<!--this div is required by the Javascript SDK--><script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");
</script>
</body>
</html>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!!

12minutes later.....BAAAAAH got the answer..Thanks anyway.. :)

Comment: add the solution as an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:
On youtube click the Share button (which is under your video), than click the Embed button. After that you'll get the code which you write in your HTML. I also checked Use old embed code, and I used that code in my HTML. Sorry if this wasn't clear. My first language is not English..but I hope I could help/